# Do I need to create an account for Nagios user in Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, nagios

I have installed Nagios on CentOS, and it's working fine.

I want to try commands from Nagios user, but when I do `su nagios` from user, I get this:

> This account is currently not available.

But the web interface is working fine. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably no problems there, it's common to disable login for daemon "users".

Check `/etc/passwd`, the login shell is probably disabled for this user. You shouldn't be executing commands as `nagios`.

Comment: About this "You shouldn't be executing commands as nagios." - why is this? I thought Nagios runs as this user when it executes commands on the client machine from the master.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But why would *you* do that? He thought there was a problem when in fact there wasn't.

Comment: I was having the same problem as him, other websites states nagios executes commands as the nagios user, which did not have a shell, so need give it a shell. So I just wondered why the nagios user shouldnt be executing commands, I got the impression it needs to.

Comment: nagios *does* execute commands as a nagios user. but not with a login shell. that's for logging in. a completely different concept.

Comment: Ok... I am using check_nrpe on the host to run the command on the client, and was getting this and many other issues. Its a nightmare.

Comment: I didn't have any problems. if you have a specific problem - post a question, please don't abuse this Q. obviously you have a different problem.

Comment: "abuse this Q?" - wow, what a thing to say. I was genuinely curious why you would say nagios shouldn't be executing commands when other sites say you have to do it, I dont see the problem with me asking this question. I have posted my issue on the Nagios forum. I am not going to hijack this thread with my own issue, I wanted to know your reasoning because I am doing it

Comment: I genuinely have no idea what your problem is. Please post a separate question. also, could you we clean this up? I don't see how this will help to future visitors.

Comment: I'm probably just misunderstanding things so just wanted an explanation. I was executing commands as nagios because nrpe is not working for me, so I'm trying to simulate nrpe executing the commands. I got the error above too. I just wondered why we shouldn't execute commands as nagios. I'm happy to delete all the other posts just wanted to know why we shouldn't execute commands as nagios.